# Primefaces selected row is null when variable is declared as Long

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have the following in ManagedBean

```
private Employee selectedEmployee; // with getter and setter    

public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {

System.out.println("selected employee "+selectedEmployee.getEmployeeNumber());

}
```

My problem is in `Employee` Entity class if I make `employeeNumber` from `String` to `Long`, I am getting null for `selectedEmployee` in `onRowSelect` method of ManagedBean

**Employee Entity** class

```
private String employeeNumber; // this works  

private Long employeeNumber; // this doesn't work
```

What could be the reason for this?

JSF Code for selection

```
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="emp" lazy="true"
value="#{myMB.lazyModel}" styleClass="userDataTableStyle"
paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="5"
selection="#{myMB.selectedEmployee}">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelectRadio" listener="#{myMB.onRowSelect}"
update=":myform:details" />
```

Comment: You should provide `rowKey` attribute in dataTable when using selection. Try to add `rowKey="#{emp.employeeNumber}"` or some other unique field and see what's happening.

Comment: @partlov I have added `rowKey="#{emp.employeeNumber}"` to `<p:ajax`, however that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: not to `p:ajax`, that attribute doesn't exist there. Add to `p:dataTable`.

Comment: @partlov Yes adding to `p:dataTable` solved the issue. Why this worked when `employeeNumber` was String? If you could add as an answer, I will be glad to accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using selection in `dataTable` you should provide `rowKey` attribute which will be used to find actual object which is selected in your list. That should be property which is unique for all data in list (probably primary key from database):

```
rowKey="#{emp.employeeNumber}"
```

I don't know actual reason why this worked with String. Maybe that was part of your `toString()` method?

Comment: That was not part of 'tostring()`

Answer (score 5):

1. You must have a Valid Primary Key in `rowKey` field.
2. You must include the `dataTable` into a form.

Else return set(null).

Comment: > You must include the dataTable into a form
That did the trick, thanks!